# Copying contents between sections in the same course on moodle

Tags: moodle

I need to copy contents of a section to another section (or clone the existing section) in the same course on moodle. I've seen some documentation on how to copy contents from one course to another but I didn't find any resources on how to copy within the course. In the image attached, there is a section "Batch 2-2021". I want to make a new section "Batch 2-2022" and copy everything from "Batch 2-2021" into it. Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Context]

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicate button for an activity

1. Go to a course
2. Turn editing on
3. Click the edit dropdown menu for an activity, select duplicate
4. Click and hold the move icon of the duplicate, then drag and drop on the new section

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Reusing_activities

Answer (score 0):

In core Moodle, you can only duplicate activities or courses, not sections. However, this functionality is available in the Mass Actions block: https://moodle.org/plugins/block_massaction

Install the block on your site and add it to the course. There are options to select all of the activities in a section and duplicate them into another section, along with many other options to apply the standard actions to multiple activities at once.

If you cannot use the Mass Actions block for some reason (on hosted Moodle site, for instance), the fastest way in core Moodle to copy a section would probably be to use a course backup. When you create the backup, you can select only the a particular section of activities. You can restore the backup into the same course, merging the data, which will create duplicates of the activities. Unfortunately, they can only be duplicated into the same section, so you'll have to manually move them to the new section. Depending on how many activities you're copying, this may not be fast than just individually duplicating and moving the activities, so the Mass Actions block is still the best option.